# Firebase AuthUI causing app to crash

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

this is my first post here, so any guidance at all is appreciated.

I'm having an issue when others download my app.  It causes the App to crash on launch.  It works perfectly when I install updates and seems to be an issue stemming from users not having a Firebase UID created when first launching.

Here is Main Activity Code:

```
package com.example.android.cellavino;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.cellavino.PojoDirectory.UI2.UserDetailsPojo;
import com.example.android.cellavino.UserInterface.WineAdapter;
import com.example.android.cellavino.UserInterface2.WineDetails.CreateNewWine;
import com.example.android.cellavino.UserInterface2.CreateTasting.MyTastings;
import com.example.android.cellavino.UserInterface2.EditProfile.EditProfile;
import com.example.android.cellavino.UserInterface2.JoinTasting.JoinTasting;
import com.example.android.cellavino.UserInterface2.WineDetails.MyWinesList;
import com.example.android.cellavino.Utils.Constants;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue;
import com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    public String mUsername;


    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mWineDatabaseReference;
    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabaseReference;
    private DatabaseReference mMyWinesReference;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;

    private FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig;
    private FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage;
    private WineAdapter mWineAdapter;
    private ListView mWineListView;
    private RecyclerView mWineRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private DrawerLayout mNavigationDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    private ListView mWineInformation;
    private TextView mWineName;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private String[] mMenuOptions;
    private Uri userProfilePic;
    private TextView mUsernameTextView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //setContentView(R.layout.my_wines_list);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_container);
        //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MyWinesListFragment()).commit();

        //Initialise Firebase
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

        //mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();


        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();

        //WineDatabase in Firebase initialisation
        mWineDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Wine Details");
        mUserDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users");
        mMyWinesReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child("myWines");


        //initialising the views
        //ListView mWineListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wineListView);


        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    //user is signed in
                    onSignedInInialise(user.getDisplayName());

                } else {
                    //user is signed out
                    onSignedOutCleanup();
                    startActivityForResult(
                            AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                    .setProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build()))
                                    .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);
                }

            }
        };

        //add code that will bring up the Add_Wine screen when a user clicks on the floating action button for addwine.

        FloatingActionButton addWineFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addWineFab);
        addWineFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateNewWine.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        //initialise view_my_wines button click listener
        Button viewMyWinesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.view_my_wines);
        viewMyWinesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyWinesList.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        //initialise edit_profile button click listener
        Button editProfileButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);
        editProfileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditProfile.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


        //initialise edit_profile button click listener
        Button createTastingButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_tasting);
        createTastingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyTastings.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        //initialise edit_profile button click listener
        Button joinTastingButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.join_tasting);
        joinTastingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, JoinTasting.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String userName = user.getDisplayName();
        if (user != null) {
            TextView mUsernameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            mUsernameTextView.setText(userName);
        } else {
            TextView mUsernameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            mUsernameTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                String uid = user.getUid();
                String userName = user.getDisplayName();
                String userEmail = user.getEmail();
                Uri userProfilePic = user.getPhotoUrl();
                createUserInFirebaseHelper(uid, userName, userEmail);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello " + userName + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign in cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void createUserInFirebaseHelper(String uid, String userName, String userEmail) {

        final String mUserName = userName;
        final String mUserEmail = userEmail;
        final Firebase userDetailLocation = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL_LOCATION_USERS).child(uid);

        //See if there is already a user (for example, if they already logged in with an associated google account

        userDetailLocation.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // If there is no user, make one
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
                    //Set raw version of date to the ServerValue.TIMESTAMP value and save into dateCreatedMap
                    HashMap<String, Object> timestampJoined = new HashMap<>();
                    timestampJoined.put(Constants.FIREBASE_PROPERTY_TIMESTAMP, ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                    UserDetailsPojo newUser = new UserDetailsPojo(mUserName, mUserEmail, timestampJoined);
                    userDetailLocation.setValue(newUser);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, getString(R.string.log_error_occurred) + firebaseError.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }

    //When the app comes back from background state etc
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }


    //When the app goes to background state
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mAuthStateListener != null) {
            mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
        }
        detachDatabaseReadListener();
        //mWineAdapter.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_navigation_drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //if (mActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        //    return true;
        //}

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.sign_out_menu:
                //sign out
                AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this);
                return true;
            /*
            case R.id.menu_add_wine:
                //add wine
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddWine.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            case R.id.view_my_wines:
                //view the working wine list Andrews Wines
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyWinesList.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                return true;

            case R.id.test_option:
                //view the test screens for Andrews Wines
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
                return true;
            */
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    private void onSignedInInialise(String username) {
        mUsername = username;
        //attachDatabaseReadListener();

        //this code adds a new user name each time it logs in.
        //mUserDatabaseReference.push().setValue(username);

    }

    private void onSignedOutCleanup() {
        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
        //mWineAdapter.clear();
        detachDatabaseReadListener();
    }

    /*
    private void attachDatabaseReadListener() {
        if (mChildEventListener == null) {
            mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    WineDetails wineDetails = dataSnapshot.getValue(WineDetails.class);
                    //mWineAdapter.add(wineDetails);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            };
            mWineDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        }
    }
*/
    private void detachDatabaseReadListener() {
        if (mChildEventListener != null) {
            mWineDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
            mChildEventListener = null;
        }
    }


    private void initializeScreen(View rootView) {
        mWineInformation = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wine_list_item_details);
        mWineName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wine_name);


    }


}
```

How can I adjust it so it checks to see if a user has a profile and if not directs them to the login page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not just copy and paste a whole junk of code, please explain where are you getting the error

Comment: Hi @Andrew. it would be good if you'd remove all the code that's not crucial to the question, to allow others to better focus on the core of the issue. You have like 300 lines of code pasted here. At the very least remove the code you've commented out.

Comment: Thanks @Mig82 - first time I've put anything here.  Will be more concise in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I was calling getDisplayName() prior to checking authentication.

Thanks for the pointers in how to post a question.  I waited 6 months before posting one as I wasn't really sure how/what to ask.  Now I know. :)